# How to disregard values in column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am wondering - how do you disregard unwanted/unnecessary values from a column once you've selected that column? For e.g., say I have a 10x2 `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['jamie', 30], ['cersei', 30], ['tyrion', 25], ['tywin', 56], ['robb', 18], ['jon', 18], ['arya', 9], ['sansa', 14], ['bran', 7], ['nedd', 42]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

print(df)

          Name          Age

0        jamie          30

1        cersei         30

2        tyrion         25

3        tywin          56

4        robb           18

5        jon            18

6        arya           9

7        sansa          14

8        bran           7

9        nedd           42
```

What if I wanted to disregard a certain value in the `'Name'` column such as `jamie`? or `'Age'` column such as anything `> 18`?

How would you go about this in a Pandas `groupby` command as well? Or disregarding unwanted values before a `plot`?

If I had a `10x4 dataframe` and wanted to look at those two columns only, I would type a groupby command: `groupby(['Name', 'Age'])`.

But if I didn't want to include the `jamie` value in the `Name` column how would I write this command?

Comment: `"How would you go about this in a Pandas groupby command as well as disregarding unwanted values "` <- please elaborate : right now its just `df[df['Name'].ne('jamie')]`

Comment: @anky_91 Hi, - I mean how would you disregard values in a `groupby` command. I edited the sentence. So `.ne(' ')` takes out unwanted values in a selected column?

Comment: You found a funny way of asking for a filter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the code after your code you will get the answer:

`print(df[df['Name']!='jamie'])
print(df[df['Age']>=18])`

Like this we can apply any condition in dataframe.

Comment: `k = df[df['Name']!='jamie']
l = k.groupby(['Name','Age'])`

Answer (score 0):

For the Age just filter with loc

```
df_01 = df.loc[df['Age'] <= 18]
```

df_01 output

```
    Name    Age
4   robb    18
5   jon     18
6   arya    9
7   sansa   14
8   bran    7
```

As for using the name 'jamie', similar approach...

```
df_02 = df.loc[df['Name'] != 'jamie']

df_02.head

    Name    Age
1   cersei  30
2   tyrion  25
3   tywin   56
4   robb    18
5   jon     18
6   arya    9
7   sansa   14
8   bran    7
9   nedd    42
```

Hoping this can be useful

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter your data.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['jamie', 30], ['cersei', 30], ['tyrion', 25], ['tywin', 56], ['robb', 18], ['jon', 18], ['arya', 9], ['sansa', 14], ['bran', 7], ['nedd', 42]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
```

Filter like this,

```
 df = df[df.Age>18]
```

returns only data with Age greater than 18.

To filter a name, try this,

```
df = df[df.Name!='jamie']
```

For each of the above examples you can create a new dataframe df_new or something similar.  Above I am modifying df by removing those entries.